# Origin https://demo.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 API I have the following on ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(x => {
  x.AddPolicy("AllowAll", y => y.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
});
```

And on Configure method I have:

```
application.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

I published the API to Azure with domain:

```
https://api-demo.example.com
```

And the web application that accesses the API is in:

```
https://demo.example.com
```

However I get an error on the web application saying:

> Origin https://demo.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-demo.example.com/v1.0/posts due to access control checks.
>   Failed to load resource: Origin https://demo.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Shouldn't `AllowAll` work in this situation? What am I missing?

**Update**

This is the order I have on Startup:

```
  application.UseHsts(); 

  application.UseCors("AllowAll");

  application.UseAuthentication();

  application.UseHealthChecks("/health");

  application.UseHttpsRedirection();

  application.UseResponseCaching();

  application.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Where is this hosted?

Comment: I am hosting it in an Azure Web App with Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header does not support wildcard `*` in combination with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`

From MDN web docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#Directives

> For requests without credentials, the literal value "*" can be specified, as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error.